# Passing extra data through the Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, android-intent, storage-access-framework

I have a `ListView` and from a click on an item of the ListView I call the Storage Access Framework (SAF).

Just before starting the SAF, I want to pass the position of the `ListView` like this:

```
intent.putExtra("Position", position);
startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

But how do I get the position back in the `onActivityResult()` method so I know which item is clicked?

I tried these lines, but with no success:

```
Bundle extras = resultData.getExtras();
Integer i = getIntent().getIntExtra("routeDataPosition", 42);
Integer i2 = resultData.getIntExtra("routeDataPosition", 42);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just before starting the SAF, I want to pass the position of the ListView like this:

That does not work. You cannot force extras into another app, and you cannot force another app to return those extras.

> But how do I get the position back in the onActivityResult() method so I know which item is clicked?

You could store it in a field in your activity, fragment, or viewmodel.

If you wanted to get elaborate, you could use a different request code based on the position. So, instead of `WRITE_REQUEST_CODE`, use `WRITE_REQUEST_CODE + position`. You would need to have smarts in `onActivityResult()` to get the position back out of the result code (e.g., `position = resultCode - WRITE_REQUEST_CODE`).

Comment: Clever solution! But I might store it in a field probably. A good reason to implement the storing of data in the methods for the activity lifecycle as well. I also do have to do that, otherwise I might be missing the items/objects in the listview after coming back from the SAF.